# Не работает maven в терминале VScode, Plugins и Dependencies тоже работают очень странно

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, maven

В консоли любая maven-команда выполняется исправно (Path я корректировал по рандомным туториалам)

- M2_HOME : C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.6
- MAVEN_HOME : C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.6
- JAVA_HOME : C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.5.8-hotspot

Но VScode не видит mvn.cmd или что-то в этом роде и не может выполнить в собственном терминале VScode например проверка версии мавена, выдаёт ошибку:

```
PS C:\scy\files\MavenTEST>mvn -version
Сбой выполнения программы mvn.cmd: Не удается найти указанный файлстрока:1 знак:1
+ mvn -version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~.
строка:1 знак:1
+ mvn -version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed'
```

Так же в вкладке Maven при открытии Plugins выдаётся ошибка "Failed to calculate Effective POM. Please check output window 'Maven for Java' for more details."

Так же в вкладке Maven при открытии Dependencies выдаётся ошибка "Error occurred in background process. spawn C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Programs\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.3.7-hotspot\bin\ ENOENT" к моему удивлению, ведь версия установленного JDK jdk-17.0.5.8-hotspot.

Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то сможет помочь решить данную проблему или скорее проблемы. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Всё решено, в переменной среды выяснилось, что в ComSpec был прописан путь к jdk вероятно из-за моего незнания, я поменял этот путь на путь к cmd и всё заработало.